# Javascript, html and react js. error in calling this.state.filteredUsers.map ((user)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have to make a modal within which I have to perform a search and complete the imput that you give me. The information I look for in an api, here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
super(props);
this.setState = {
  users: [],
  filteredUsers: []
 };
}


componentDidMount () {
fetch('/users')
  .then((resp) => resp.json())
  .then((users) => {
    this.setState({ users });
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
}


 search (e) {
let value = e.target.value;
// hace un filtrado del array de usuarios para obtener
// aquellos cuyo nombre contiene lo ingresado en el input
let filteredUsers = this.state.users.filter((user) => {
  return user.name.includes(value);
});
// actualiza el estado y por ende, la tabla
this.setState({
  filteredUsers
});
}

render() {
return (
  <div className="App">
    <div className="App-header">
      <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
      <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
    </div>
    <p className="App-intro">
      To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
    </p>

    <button type="button" className="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>


    <div id="myModal" className="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div className="modal-dialog">


        <div className="modal-content">
          <div className="modal-header">
            <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 className="modal-title">Add Note</h4>
          </div>
          <div className="modal-body">
            <h5 className="modal-title">New Note </h5>
            <input 
                type="text" 
                id="myInput" 
                name="search"   
                placeholder="Search.."
                title="Type in a name"
                onChange={this.search.bind(this)}     
            ></input>

          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>Company</th>
                <th>website</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {
              this.state.filteredUsers.map((user) => (
                <tr>
                  <td>{user.name}</td>
                  <td>{user.username}</td>
                  <td>{user.email}</td>
                  <td>{user.address}</td>
                  <td>{user.phone}</td>
                  <td>{user.company}</td>
                  <td>{user.website}</td>
                </tr>
              ))
            }
            </tbody>
          </table> 

          </div>
          <div className="modal-footer">
            Import: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck"></input>
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Add Note</button>
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">cancelar</button>

          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>






     );
 }
}
export default App;
```

In theory the code should do is find the info in the api and go autocompleting, everything works fine until I put the body of the table, when I add that block of code I try to run the program the only thing I get is a white screen and I do not know why.

To the moment that I remove that block of code the program runs perfect

What is happening in that block of code that does not render anything?

Comment: and the errors  in your browser console are....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I see is that you don't have a key attribute in your loop elements, it should be something like this:

```
this.state.filteredUsers.map((user, index) => (
    <tr key={index}>
        ...
    </tr>
));
```

Also bear in mind that react will not guarantee that the state will be updated immediately:

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a
>   pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value. [react docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

This here is a great article that could help you understand more the problem. [3 Reasons why I stopped using React.setState](https://medium.com/@mweststrate/3-reasons-why-i-stopped-using-react-setstate-ab73fc67a42e#.c9ne2dk3l)

Comment: And what should I put in that  key attribute?

Comment: The Key attr is basically an identifier, something that is different between all elements. If you are iterating through a collection of blog post then maybe a blogID would be in order, in this case the index will do the job.